# It is there a possible way to create some Global Steps Hooks in parallel execution for cucumber 4?

Tags: parallel-processing, cucumber, hook, global, cucumber-jvm

Parallel execution of cucumber 4 work for me, but I want to execute some actions just once for all tests, It is a possible way to run some hooks in another Thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement, you want to execute some actions for all test cases once, is it like before or after all test case execution. If so then adding @BeforeClass from JUnit/TestNG and Similarly you can use @AfterClass in your run cuke class. This piece of code would run once before running your first class and after all test execution completed.

would it may work or adding tagged hooks give you some clue. Like for some specific test cases you can use tagged hooks and run those specific actions inside that hook only.

Comment: yea, @BeforeClass work in this case


`@BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        System.out.println("Before Junit Class : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}`

Comment: It would be good if you accept the answer and it would be useful for others as well.